# Django only seems to allow one project's models at once

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm working in Django and I have 2 apps (monitor and maintenance) in a single project. I can't seem to figure out why when one app's models.py is working, the other one doesn't. Here's my debug output, but it doesn't seem to make any sense because I AM setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Both apps worked until I added models to one of them. Then "monitor" died. When I changed the models in monitor, maintenance had this happen.

Debug output:

```
    Connected to pydev debugger (build 139.1659)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2217, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/REPOS/client-product-controller/Web/myproject/maintenance/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from models import Control
  File "C:/REPOS/client-product-controller/Web/myproject/maintenance\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Control(models.Model):
  File "C:/REPOS/client-product-controller/Web/myproject/maintenance\models.py", line 6, in Control
    control_label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

here's my wsgi.py

```
    import os
# import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and in my maintenance/views.py

```
...    
from models import Control
..
```

and in my maintenance/models.py

```
...
class Control(models.Model):
    control_label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...
```

I haven't changed any code in maintenance. and the SAME error was happening in monitor just moments ago. I'm not sure what changed, but I did do a migration and syncdb

Comment: Wild guess: Try setting different Table spaces for the models in each file as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/tablespaces/

Comment: @Basic I will still give it a try, that's from that page's docs, and I'm using SQLite. thank you

: 
Database support¶

PostgreSQL and Oracle support tablespaces. SQLite and MySQL don’t.

When you use a backend that lacks support for tablespaces, Django ignores all tablespace-related options.

Comment: Just realized that this issue was a problem having the debugger improperly configured. The debugger wasn't hitting wsgi.py, and not adding DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Comment: I thought it might be that but then you said it worked for one set of models, which seems counter-intuitive. Anyway, glad you got it sorted